# A drop down list of all content in wordpress and show url

Tags: php, jquery, database, wordpress, plugins

Is there a plugin or another way...
Basically in the backend of wordpress I want the user to be able to select a file or page from a drop down list and then it displays the URL so they can copy and paste it for easy linking?

**Example:**

```
they select a file
    document.pdf
and in a box below it displays the URL
    /wp-content/uploads/2013/10/document.pdf
```

so then they can copy and paste that URL into their content?
Been looking for a while to figure this out but no luck as of yet!

I'm also using Advanced Custom Fields if this can help?

//=================================== SOLVED ====================================//
This code gets the ID of the select field (#acf-field-select_content) and gets the value of the currently selected option. It then places the value in the text field (#acf-field-show_content_url) but in front of the ID I echo the 'SERVER_NAME' and '?p=' which is Wordpress's default permalink option.. This way sadly doesn't link straight to the file but to attachment page which is not such a big problem in this case

```
$serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; 
?>
<script>  
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#acf-field-select_content").change(function() {
            var str = "http://<?php echo $serverName; ?>/?p=";
            jQuery("option:selected", this).each(function() {
                str += jQuery(this).val();
            });
            jQuery("#acf-field-show_content_url").val(str);
        })
        .trigger("change");
    });
</script>
<?php }
add_filter('admin_head', 'add_admin_code');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Advanced Custom Fields for something like this. You can create a field with the 'File Upload' type. It'd be great if you had the paid add-on for 'Repeater' as well. The repeater would allow for you to have a repeatable list of files without the need to create a separate field for each uploaded file.

Check it out! [ACF Repeater Add-on [link]](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/).

But, without the plugin - you'll need to create a separate field for each uploaded file and do something like this:

```
<?php
 // Get file url and title
 $uploaded_file_1 = get_field('uploaded_file_1');
 $uploaded_file_1_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $uploaded_file_1 );
 $uploaded_file_1_title = get_the_title( $uploaded_file_1 );
?>

<!-- create dropdown with list of file names and urls -->
<select id="files">
    <option value="">
        Select a file
    </option>
    <option value="<?php echo $uploaded_file_1_url; ?>">
        <?php echo $uploaded_file_1_title; ?>
    </option>
</select>

 <input type="text" id="file-info">

 <script>
  // bind change event to dropdown, when you change the dropdown
  // get the value of the selected option and put it in the input field
  document.getElementById('files').onchange = function(){     
     document.getElementById('file-info').value = document.getElementById('files').value;
 }
 </script>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N7ujB/

### If you have the repeater field add-on

You'll create a repeater field with a field name of something like, 'Files'. Within the repeater field you'll create a field for 'File Title' and 'File Upload'.

Next, you''ll loop through the repeater field to display all the uploaded documents.

```
<!-- create dropdown with list of file names and urls -->
<select id="files">
    <option value="">
        Select a file
    </option>
    <?php

    if ( get_field('files') ) {
        // loop through the uploaded files
        while(has_sub_field('files')) {

            // set variables for file title/uri
            $file = get_sub_field('file_upload');
            $file_uri = wp_get_attachment_url( $file );
            $file_title = ( get_sub_field('file_title') ) ? get_sub_field('file_title') : get_the_title( $file );

            // generate code for each option, including the file uri and title
            echo '<option value="' . $file_uri . '">' . $file_title . '</option>';
        }
    }

    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I do have the repeater field! How can i do this? :)

Comment: I've updated my original answer. If you use that code you'll need to be sure you name your repeater fields 'Files', 'File Upload', and 'File Title' to work properly.

Comment: Sadly after re-reading your answer its not what im looking for! Im looking for this to be only visible in the backend for the 'user'.. This is for quick reference so they can just select the file or page and it displays the url so they can copy and paste it into the content field

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an associative array of 'file name'=>'file url'.
2. Create drop down displaying all 'file name' elements of the array using for each loop.
3. Save the matching 'file url' value of the selected 'file name' using global $customFields (on the backend it's called $custom.
4. Display the 'file url' vlue on the front end using $customFields.